# How can i get title of window in cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm just getting started with Objective-C and I'm writing a simple application.
I made two outlets :
    + wnd - main window
    + display - the text box

I want to put window title into the text box. But, i can not get the window title.
Does anyone can show me how to get it to work?
Thank a lot.

Comment: There is no such thing called window title, are you looking for root  view controller title or navigation bar title that is present on window ?

Comment: Are you writing an app for OS X or for iOS?

Comment: :), OSX. Can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the title property of NSWindow.

```
display.stringValue = wnd.title;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it :)